# Weird Java error with new DefaultHttpClient()

Tags: java, apache, http

Getting the following error from my Bukkit plugin, for some reason. Line 58 of `UpdatePlayer.java`, where the error is starting, is `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`

```
2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at com.adventurize.players.UpdatePlayer.run(UpdatePlayer.java:58)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:316)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.newFactory(LogFactory.java:517)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2.run(LogFactory.java:531)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.<init>(LogFactoryImpl.java:95)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.initDiagnostics(LogFactoryImpl.java:476)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getClassLoader(LogFactoryImpl.java:447)

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;

2013-07-06 21:22:28
[SEVERE] Exception in thread "Thread-8"
```

This was all working fine on the first server I tried the plugin on, but then we switched servers and I'm getting this error. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: check for java versions and commons-logging versions on both the servers

Comment: I don't have access to the older server. The current one is as follows: `commons-logging`: `1.1.1`, `java`: `1.7.0_21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the exception is *saying* is that the version of `LogFactory` that the classloader loaded doesn't have a method with the signature:

```
    Classloader LogFactory.getClassLoader(Class)
```

What is going on is that your application (or some 3rd party JAR) was compiled against one version of the `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` API, but your runtime is loading a different version.

According to the project's online javadocs, the `getClassLoader(Class)` method is present in the `1.1.x` versions of the commons logging, but not in the `1.0.4` version.  (It is an semi-internal method ... it declared `protected` ... so the dependency is more likely to be from some JAR that implements or extends log4j rather than from client code.)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks very much for that!